# How to loop over nested array in react?

Tags: reactjs, loops, nested-loops

Let's say I have this faq array as one of my states:

```
this.state = {
    faqs: [
        {
            section: "Section One",
            faqList: [
                {
                    question: "Q1",
                    answer: "A1"
                },
                {
                    question: "Q1",
                    answer: "A1"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            section: "Section Two",
            faqList: [
                {
                    question: "Q1",
                    answer: "A1"
                },
                {
                    question: "Q1",
                    answer: "A1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And I'd like to render them. This is how I tried to do it currently:

```
render() {

    const faqs = this.state.faqs;

    return (
    <div>   
        {faqs.map(faqSec => {

            return (
                <h2>{faqSec.section}</h2>

                {faqSec.faqList.map(faq => {
                    return (
                        <p>faq.question</p> 
                        <p>faq.answer</p>                                           
                    )
                })}

            )
        })}
    </div>
    );
}
```

However, an error occurs due to the nested map function:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected , (80:8)
```

How do I loop through this nested object properly?

Comment: You're doing right at the first glance. Give us the code of lines 78-82 and I'll give you the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the list of map result in a root element:

```
return (
  <div>{/* use key here */}
   <h2>{faqSec.section}</h2>
   {faqSec.faqList.map(faq => {
     return (
      <div>{/* use key here */}
       <p>faq.question</p>
       <p>faq.answer</p>                                           
      </div>
     )
   })}
 </div>
)
```

Alternatively, you may return array of elements:

```
return [
   <h2>{faqSec.section}</h2>,{/* use key here */}
   {faqSec.faqList.map(faq => {
     return [
       <p>faq.question</p>,{/* use key here */}
       <p>faq.answer</p>{/* use key here */}
     ]
   })}
 ]
```

Or, even you can use [Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html):

```
return (
      <React.Fragment>{/* use key here */}
       <h2>{faqSec.section}</h2>
       {faqSec.faqList.map(faq => {
         return (
          <React.Fragment>{/* use key here */}
           <p>faq.question</p>
           <p>faq.answer</p>                                           
          </React.Fragment>
         )
       })}
     </React.Fragment>
    )
```

You may use short-hand syntax for `<React.Fragment></React.Fragment>` as well:

```
<></>
```

Not all tool supports short-hand syntax. See [this](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/11/28/react-v16.2.0-fragment-support.html#support-for-fragment-syntax) if you want to use shorthand syntax.

**Ensure to use key uniquely as commented above.**

Answer (score 4):

You have to put the tags in a parent tags. React will not print this two tag separately. You have to bind this two tag with a parent tag.

```
render() {

const faqs = this.state.faqs;

return (
 <div>   
    {faqs.map(faqSec => {

        return (
           <div>
              <h2>{faqSec.section}</h2>

              {faqSec.faqList.map(faq => {
                  return (
                     <div>
                        <p>{faq.question}</p> 
                        <p>{faq.answer}</p> 
                     </div>                                          
                  )
              })}
          </div>
        )
    })}
</div>
);
```

}

You also miss the {} bracket in your code. Please check this code. I hope it will work for you.